# Listado de opciones para setlocale en C y uso

Tags: c

A lo mejor es una pregunta muy extensa, pero es que son dos cosas que forman parte del mismo problema:
En la librería locale.h se supone que se encuentran las opciones internacionales para C, peor por más que busco no encuentro ningún listado con el comando de cada país.
Para poder usar acentos , ñ, y demás caracteres especiales en español uso la orden setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "spanish");
y funciona bien, pero para el resto de posibilidades de esta librería, como LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, no me funciona el mismo comando, ni consigo introducir separador de miles, ni la coma en decimales, en lugar de punto.
¿Alguna idea? Os aseguro que llevo días buscando por internet y lo más que encuentro son ejemplos sueltos para alemán o inglés.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Prueba con `setlocale( LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8" );` Suponiendo, claro está, que tu sistema tenga este *locale* instalado.

Comment: @Trauma justo le iba a escribir eso jajajajaja

Comment: No me funciona. Para los caracteres especiales tengo que poner "spanish", no me reconoce "es_ES". Y para elresto de las cosas, ni cambiando la codificación a UTF8, ni nada. Tiene que haber otro sistema.

Comment: No te funciona porque tu sistema no lo tiene instalado. Los *locales* no son *universales*, depende de otras partes de tu sistema.

Comment: ¿Y hay alguna forma de saber lo que tengo instalado o instalarlo? Tengo windows 10.